# What is 1200p HD?

Tags: video, video-quality

I'm looking to purchase a borescope, and many of them state their video quality as "1200p" HD.  Surprisingly, I've found *nothing* definitive as to what that means.  The closest answer I could find was [this answer here on another forum](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/does-1920x1200-mean-i-have-1200p.2475572/#post-38275936) which says "As far as 1200p, most commonly I think that would be interpreted as 1920x1200".

So here's the question: is it a "real" term, like ["1080p"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p), and if so, why doesn't it have a canonical reference like the Wikipedia article for 1080p?  Does it refer to any resolutions that have 1200 lines of progressive scanning, such as 1600x1200 (4:3 aspect ratio) or 1920x1200 (16:10 aspect ratio)?  If someone only says their product is 1200p, then what resolution (and thus aspect ratio) can I assume that is?

Comment: If the other products that advertise 1200p do provide a resolution, and it's the same resolution, that's a safe bet. Else, there's no standard value to fall back on.

Answer (score 1):

1080p is aspect ration 16:9 and 1200p is 16:10 - exactly as you wrote. You find useful information here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2132850/1080p-1200p-gaming.html

Comment: It's worth noting that 1080p is an official standard defined by SMPTE and others, while 1200p is a fairly unusual marketing term.

Comment: 1920×1200 is a fairly common ratio for computer displays. (Not _nearly_ as common as 1080p, especially since HDTV was defined, but fairly common.) The first widely-sold desktop consumer LCD display, SGI's 1600SW from 1998, had a 1600×1024 resolution (25:16 aspect, wider than 4:3 but less than 16:9). That set the tone for a certain degree of resistance to switching from the traditional 4:3 aspect all the way to full 16:9 widescreen, since there's real value to having additional height in a PC display. (Rotatable displays, though also not very common, are similarly a product of that tension.)